# Recent Upgrade Breaks USB boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, usb

So I realize as a new user - I very well might get some flak, but here is my current setup, process before upgrade, upgrade issue and request for assistance.

Setup:
Laptop with SSD-0 and Ubuntu Installed 
SSD-0 primary boot configuration written to SSD-0
Thumbdrive with Antergos Installed as USB-1
Antergos boot configuration written to USB-1

Process before upgrade:
If Thumbdrive USB-1 present at boot
Splashscreen presented options

```
a. Boot Antergos on USB-1 
b. Boot Antergos Fallback
c. Boot Ubuntu
d. Boot Ubuntu Fallback
```

If Thumbdrive USB-1 not present at boot

```
a. Boot Ubuntu
b. Boot Ubuntu Fallback
```

Process after Upgrade
If Thumbdrive USB-1 present at boot
Splashscreen presented options

```
a. Boot Ubuntu
b. Boot Ubuntu Fallback
```

If Thumbdrive USB-1 not present at boot

```
a. Boot Ubuntu
b. Boot Ubuntu Fallback
```

All through the upgrade - (most recent release) no questions were asked in terms of keeping or replacing user specific files.  What is concerning is boot information for each of the OS implementations were written to the installation drive separately as to not have these boot overwrite issues.

That said - I am asking what tool and relating process to return to a state where I can successfully boot the USB-1 drive from this laptop.

Thanks in advance

EDIT 
- boot configurations written local to the respective drives - ubuntu on ssd and antergos on usb.

In addition tried toggling the BIOS setting to allow legacy and uefi - and placed usb in higher order than ssd - all to no avail (why I'm asking here)
END EDIT

Comment: Looks like the boot entry order in UEFI settings has changed, please enter your UEFI settings and check the boot order.

Comment: See Edits for clarification...  How is this expected behavior when USB and SSD boot configurations were written independent of the other.  And what was before upgrade is the expected bahaviour.

Comment: OK. I got it now. The key is to understand that grub is loaded from the USB when USB is attached. However, it looks like now instead of booting from the USB and using the bootloader in USB, now the laptop boots from SSD even when the USB is attached. Since that bootloader (grub or whatever Antergos uses) is part of Antargos, and not Ubuntu, this problem is with either the, UEFI/BIOS, or the USB drive or Antargos, which is not an official version of Ubuntu. Thus, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Except for the fact the upgrade specifically changed something when USB-1 was not present - thus preventing any USB boot at all.  I have 2 of these drives installed this way and neither work and I would insist Ubuntu upgrade problems are not off topic since the modification resluted from Upgrade process - (yes to the laptop boots laptop only - no usb boot anymore)

Comment: Is there a chance upgrade process does something regarding disk drive recognition or making them available at boot? (not bios specific entries here but fstab?)

Comment: There are two possibilities. One, something changed in UEFI/BIOS that is stopping USB boot. Two, something messed up the USB drives making then not recognized as boot drives by UEFI. Neither of these can be done by updating Ubuntu. The fstab file in Ubuntu is read much later in the boot process. It only keeps partition information about Ubuntu. It is not needed for booting from external drives.

Comment: Thanks user68186 - you mentioned uefi - it is acting like windows 10 acts with secure boot, and while no-one wants to claim responsibility - the upgrade process does write information to the boot configurations and bios (how do the menu options get written in bios that specifically says ubuntu?)

Comment: Can you boot another computer with your Antergos USB?

Comment: thanks for feedback - I can boot usb on other computer, and I believe I have come to understand what the upgrade changed that prevented usb booting.

So there is a bios option which became enabled for "OS Optimized Defaults" Disabling this option and rebooting allowed for USB boot.

Any chance you can point me to a reference for what options are written to Bios during Installation or upgrade - Where does the bios boot options get written to and saved - because how drives are referenced will matter in terms of knowing where to load the kernel from - I'm not convinced this is resolved yet.

Comment: Nothing is written to UEFI or BIOS during Ubuntu updates. Updating Ubuntu does not enable "OS optimized defaults" in UEFI. You have to do it yourself. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070217/should-i-enable-os-optimized-defaults-in-uefi-when-dual-booting-windows-and-ub for more on this option.

Comment: I did an upgrade, not an update and it was a full version upgrade....  So what adds the ubuntu entries in BIOS then - cause it wasn't me and it wasnt antergos, and it changed when I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a bios option which became enabled for "OS Optimized Defaults" as a result of the recent upgrade.

Once I Disabled this option, and rebooted, my USB drives are now recognized and loaded, restoring the expected behavior prior to upgrading the Ubuntu Operating system.

I am willing to consider other answers which fully explain what entries are or created or modified by the OS and available to BIOS having to do with the following:

1. Bios Entries to load specific operating systems such as "Ubuntu"
2. Bios entries for OS Optimized default behaviors and how it gets set or modified
3. Recognition of boot-able partitions and drive availability at bios startup and how they are identified or loaded in Ubuntu operating systems which may have been created or modified by the upgrade